# Typescript merge mapped type created from union type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a mapped type from a union type of keys. For the sake of having a minimal example, the types simply map to themselves. The following generic returns the expected result

```js
type Foo<Bar extends string> = {[name in Bar]: name}
type test = Foo<'test1' | 'test2'> //test = {test1: 'test1', test2: 'test2'}
```

However, i want to remove the string contraint and just return `undefined` if `Bar` is not a string. I did this in the following way

```js
type Foo<Bar> = Bar extends string ? {[name in Bar]: name} : undefined
type test = Foo<'test1' | 'test2'>
//expected result: test = {test1: 'test1', test2: 'test2'}
//actual result: test = {test1: 'test1'} | {test2: 'test2'}
```

`test` is now a union type instead of a simple mapped type.

Is this expected behavior in typescript or should i file a bug report? And is there any way to get the behavior i want?

P.S. In case it can be of assistance, i'm trying to fix [this](https://github.com/wix-incubator/as-typed/blob/master/index.d.ts#L100) line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is expected behavior, it's often useful feature called [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).

But sometimes, like in your example, it gets in the way. The workaround is to wrap `Bar` type parameter in `[]` [when it's used in condition test](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29368):

```
type Foo1<Bar extends string> = {[name in Bar]: name}
type test1 = Foo1<'test1' | 'test2'> //test1 = {test1: 'test1', test2: 'test2'}

type Foo2<Bar> = [Bar] extends [string] ? {[name in Bar]: name} : undefined;
type test2 = Foo2<'test1' | 'test2'> //test2 = {test1: 'test1', test2: 'test2'}
type test3 = Foo2<1>; // undefined
```